# Check T is IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am using a session extension in asp.net core 6 as below:

```
public static T? Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
{
    var value = session.GetString(key);
    return value == null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
}
```

When passing Lists, I'd rather get a new class object instead of default (which is null)

```
List<SavedQueries> savedQueries = Context.Session.Get<List<SavedQueries>>("SavedQueries");
```

Here, savedQueries is null, which cause further problems. I am using some temporary workaround here:

```
if (savedQueries is null) savedQueries = new List<SavedQueries>();
```

How can I make the extension method aware of IEnumerable and return new T() accordingly? something like we did in older .net versions:

```
public static T? Get<T>(this ISession session, string key) where T : IEnumerable
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? new T(): JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
```

> Error: Using the generic type 'IEnumerable' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why doesn't `savedQueries ?? new List<SavedQueries>()` not work? A `List<T>` already is an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`

Comment: "_How can I make the extension method aware of IEnumerable_". It already is, due to the generic constraint you defined. You probably just forgot to import/use the System.Collections namespace. "_return new T() accordingly_". Add the `new()` constraint to the already existing generic constraint for your Get<T> method.

Comment: By the way, `JsonSerializer` doesn't support deserializing into an interface like `IEnumerable` so you need to pick a concrete type like `List<T>` or `Array<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IsAssignableFrom`. You need a `new()` constraint to create an instance of any enumerable:

```
public static T? Get<T>(this ISession session, string key) where T: new()
{
    string value = session.GetString(key);
    if (value != null) 
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
    else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        return new T();
    }

    return default;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your where statement should be

```
where T : System.Collections.IEnumerable , new()
```

Or else add a

```
using System.Collections;
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach like below should work :

```
var ienum =typeof(IEnumerable<>);
var isImplemented = typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Any(r=> r.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == ienum))
```

It basically enlists all the interface implemented loop through generic ones and checks if any of them has a generic definition like `IEnumerable<>`